# How firebug count the total length of Content (for examples image) in Firebug

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebug

I am using Firebug and want to know how the Net panel count the content length. For example I open Msdn.com and trying to check the site.

The spirit image file they use is itself 39 KB file. The firebug tell me the total is 31. (26KB) from cache.

[image: Firebug screenshot]

Comment: the image might be compressed while delivering

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the Content-Length HTTP header, not necessarily the final size of the asset. Servers will often compress content for browsers capable of receiving it, this saves bytes in transmission.

Answer (score 0):

You may see on your hard drive there is shown two types of sizes one is **size** and another is **size on disk** like this 39kb of file is showing 31kb.

Comment: Thanks for help, When my Firefox download it from Server is it 31KB or 39KB ?

Comment: I think when download it from server it is 31kb(size) and after on your drive it would be 39kb(size on disk)